# split array and display table in ASP classic? how to?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, split

Table Room

```
ID:1 | OFName: Room1

ID:2 | OFName: Room2

ID:3 | OFName: Room3
```

Table Document

```
ID:12 | Code:123/PA | RoomID: 1,2,3

ID:13 | Code:12/HC  | RoomID: 2

ID:14 | Code:121/CA | RoomID: 2,3

ID:15 | Code:141/PC | RoomID: 1,3
```

And I want display like this

Room1

```
ID | Code

12 | 123/PA

15 | 141/PC
```

Room2

```
ID | Code

12 | 123/PA

13 | 12/HC

15 | 141/PC
```

I write like this but err !

```
<%
SQLDV = " Select ID,OFName From Room" 
CREATECONNECTION()
rs.open SQLDV,ObjConn,1 ,3 
While not rs.eof
response.write("" & rs(" OFName ") & "")
%>
<%
        Create2ndRs()
            SQLSearch = "SELECT ID,Code From Document"
            ListArray = split(RoomID, ",")
                For i = 0 to UBound(ListArray)-1
                    sqlWhere =sqlWhere & " (ListArray(i)=" & rs("ID") & ") "
                Next
                SQLSearch = SQLSearch & "where" & sqlWhere
                rs1.open SQLSearch,ObjConn,1 ,3 
                While not rs1.eof 
                    response.write("" & rs1("ID") & "","" & rs1("Code") & "")
                rs1.movenext
                wend
        rs1.close
rs.movenext
wend
CLOSECONNECTION()%>
```

Comment: What error description are you getting?

Comment: The ListArray in your For loop is a variable, you try to put it in a string. I don't think SQL understands (ListArray(i) = <ID>). And what is that quote after rs("ID") & ") '" ?. Try to print your SQL statement, then you'll see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have four lines of code which are just not going to work, each of these will give you its own error. You cant do this:

```
response.write(" & "rs(" OFName ") & "")
```

This should be something like (always use trim even if you don't think you need it, its just a good practice...):

```
response.write trim(rs("OFName"))
```

The way you ahve 'ListArray(i)' is inside a string.  You cant do this:

```
sqlWhere = sqlWhere & " (ListArray(i)=" & rs("ID") & ") '"
```

This should be something like:

```
sqlWhere = sqlWhere & "(" & trim(ListArray(i)) & "=" & trim(rs("ID")) & ")"
```

You dont have a space after our table name and before the where, so this:

```
SQLSearch = SQLSearch & "where" & sqlWhere
```

should be

```
SQLSearch = SQLSearch & " where " & sqlWhere
```

Nor can you do this:

```
response.write("" & rs1("ID") & "","" & rs1("Code") & "")
```

I imagine you need:

```
response.write trim(rs1("ID")) & "," & trim(rs1("Code"))
```

Comment: @Nguyen you really need to read up on how to use forums.  Just saying still err is just lazy.  Are we supposed to guess your error.

Comment: @Mat41 Sounds like you also *"need to read up on how to use forums"* because [so] isn't one.